# jQuery ajax - trigger fail callback function only when all retry failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use ajax with jQuery, as we know `$.ajax` return a promise `ajaxPromise`. My requirement is: only when all ajax call retries are failed, `ajaxPromise` catch the failure (I want to handle error within ajax promise callback function).

I tried following code:

```
function ajax(data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: data,
    triedCount: 0,
    retryLimit: 3,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log("error: " + this.triedCount);
      this.triedCount++;
      if (this.triedCount < this.retryLimit) {
        $.ajax(this);
      }
    }
  });
}

var ajaxPromise = ajax({"id": "123"});
ajaxPromise.fail(function(xhr) {
  console.log("All retries failed...");
  // all retries failed, handle error
});
```

Output what I want is:

```
error: 0
error: 1
error: 2
All retries failed...
```

While actually the output is:

```
error: 0
All retries failed...
error: 1
error: 2
```

Looks like `fail` callback is triggered immediately after the first call fails, while I want `fail` callback triggered after all retries are failed.

Is there any way that only when all retries are failed then trigger `ajaxPromise.fail` callback? Or is there other options can do this?

Comment: do you know how twisted is the scoping in javascript? i am not sure, but i believe in that nested ajax call, your `triedCount` variable is lost. maybe try to pass the variable in the call back and then in the ajax call as an option?

Comment: Do you know in advance which header is returned ? If yes, you can used statuCode callback.

Comment: @MridulKashyap `triedCount ` variable has no scoping problem:)

Comment: @coderz: I suggest you push all the `promises` (including the retry promise)of the ajax calls in an array

Comment: why not once you are trying with **async : false**

Comment: @MickeyPatel `async: false` will block all async calls (sometimes even block 3rd party libraries), it is better not to use it if there is other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ajax(data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: data,
    triedCount: 0,
    retryLimit: 3,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log("error: " + this.triedCount);
      this.triedCount++;
      if (this.triedCount < this.retryLimit) {
        console.log(this);
        $.ajax(this);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

in your code here, you're calling the ajax function if an error occurred. but that doesn't mean the previous ajax call didn't complete. the first ajax call completes and send the return value(failure). your

```
ajaxPromise.fail(function(xhr) {
 console.log("All retries failed...");
  // all retries failed, handle error
});
```

runs, and you get "All retries failed..." is logged on to console. 
if you want to achieve what you want to achieve you'll have to intercept the previous result and prevent it from being returned. instead, check if 3 tries have been completed and then return the value. but i'm not sure how to do that.

***EDIT***: after long research i found it's just not possible. you should give up trying to do such a thing.. just kidding! check this code, i believe this is exactly what you want:

```js
// Code goes here

function ajax(data) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: data,
    triedCount: 0,
    retryLimit: 3,
    success: function(){
      dfd.resolve("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log("error: " + this.triedCount);
      this.triedCount++;
      if (this.triedCount < this.retryLimit) {
        $.ajax(this);
      }
      else{
        dfd.reject(xhr);
      }
    }
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
var ajaxPromise = ajax({"id": "123"});
ajaxPromise.fail(function(xhr) {
  console.log("All retries failed...");
  // all retries failed, handle error
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: the error throws from the failed ajax call will be available in `xhr` parameter of `ajaxPromise` callback.

Comment: I'm still looking for a way btw. will update if i find something.

Comment: Maybe `differed`, `then` helps?

Comment: How is updated Answer different from http://stackoverflow.com/a/39031614/? What is `this` and `xhr` at `.fail()` chained to `ajaxPromise`?

Comment: it uses the same method to achieve the goal. but as you can see, this code is quite close to the original code OP posted. also, i'd like to think it's cleaner and easier to understand for beginners(like myself). about `xhr` yes, i forgot to add the returned value in `.reject()`. thank you for pointing out. i'll update it.

Comment: _"it uses the same method to achieve the goal"_ What is purpose of updating Answer to same approach from another Answer? What do you mean by "cleaner"? Note, `errorThrown` is not the same as `xhr`. What is `this` set to at `.fail()` chained to `ajaxPromise`?

Comment: Great! While when I want to `console.log(xhr)` in `ajaxPromise.fail` function it output undefiend, how to put `xhr` to `ajax` function return value?

Comment: @coderz _"how to put xhr to ajax function return value?"_ See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39031614/

Comment: you can call the `responseText` property to see what went wrong. in your anonymous method use `console.log(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: check this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/EUhFffZEvK6pxWXL4aMo?p=preview) idk why the `responseText` is not showing here.

Comment: @MridulKashyap Thanks! Great answer, I learned a lot (like `Deferred`) from this answer:) I'm go through related document to learn more.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. happy coding :). by the way, would you like if wrote an explanation of `deferred` methods here? i didn't as i know there are plenty of explanations(and quite detailed) out there already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.Deferred()`, `.rejectWith()`; call a recursive function with `beforeStart` of `$.Deferred()` with `ajaxOptions` passed as parameter; if `this.triedCount` is not less than `this.retryLimit`, return rejected deferred object with `this` set to current ajax options, `xhr` passed as parameter to `.fail()` chained to `ajaxPromise`

```js
function ajax(data) {
  var ajaxOptions = {
    url: "...",
    data: data,
    triedCount: 0,
    retryLimit: 3
  };
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    function request(opts) {
      $.ajax(opts)
        .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("error: " + this.triedCount);
          this.triedCount++;
          if (this.triedCount < this.retryLimit) {
            return request(this)
          } else {
            dfd.rejectWith(this, [xhr])
          }
        })
    }
    request(ajaxOptions)
  })
}

var ajaxPromise = ajax({
  "id": "123"
});
ajaxPromise.fail(function(xhr) {
  console.log("All retries failed...", xhr);
  // all retries failed, handle error
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```